# Sitecore Intranet Portal: How to change the default structuring of User profiles

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-intranet-portal

I am using Sitecore Intranet Portal. The user profiles are saved in folders which are created by default. E.g. For a user "`Jonny Bravo`" two folders `J` and `Jo` are created automatically and then the user profile is saved in it.

```
 `J -> Jo -> Jonny Bravo`
```

I would like to disable this default behavior instead I want to structure the user profiles according to departments. E.g. Finance, Purchase, Administration etc. So a folder `Purchase` would contains all the users working in this department.

Please let me know if:

**1. Its possible or not ?**

**2. Does it has any consequences ?**

Comment: Which SIP version do you use?

Comment: I am using SIP version 4.0.

Comment: See the answer below. I guess it's the same in SIP 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitecore Intranet Portal 4.1.0, in `Intranet.Profiles.config` config, you can define your own `UserProfileProvider` instead of the default one, which uses `Sitecore.Intranet.Profiles.Providers.UserProfileProvider` class.

Just inherit from that class and override `public virtual Item GetProfileFolder(string userName, bool createIfNotExist)` method.

Default implementation of this method is:

```cs
public virtual Item GetProfileFolder(string userName, bool createIfNotExist)
{
    userName = StringUtil.GetLastPart(userName, '\\', userName);
    Item item = this.settings.Database.GetItem(this.settings.UserProfilesFolder);
    int num = Math.Min(this.settings.UserProfilesTreeDepth, userName.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        string firstLetters = this.GetFirstLetters(userName, i + 1);
        Item item2 = this.GetItem(item, firstLetters, TemplateIDs.Folder);
        if (item2 == null)
        {
            if (!createIfNotExist)
            {
                return item;
            }
            item = this.CreateFolder(item, firstLetters);
        }
        else
        {
            item = item2;
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

I don't know about any disadvantages of changing default folder structure.

---

**EDIT**

You need to change the type of the provider to you custom provider here:

```xml
<UserProfileProvider>
  <x:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Intranet.Profiles.Providers.UserProfileProvider, Sitecore.Intranet.Profiles</x:attribute>
  <param ref="profilesSettings"/>
</UserProfileProvider>
```

Comment: By the way can you please give me the link where you get the code you used in the answer. I would like to see the others methods as well. Thanks!!